# Magento 2 website redirecting constantly

Tags: magento-2.1, redirect

I installed my new **Magento2** page on the domain yesterday but I keep get an error that I cannot manage to solve. Where am I making a mistake.

> The page isn’t redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or
>   refusing to accept cookies.

I cannot figure out what is going wrong where

domain: 
www.thefixedgearshop.com

When changing the `web/url/redirect_to_base` to 0 in **`phpmyadmin`** I get the website back and can browse around but my backend is not reachable. Also the font-awesome icons are not displayed.

Comment: have you done static content deploy?